# Deep or Shallow Copy when Inserting Data to a Data Structure?

Tags: c++, memory, data-structures, insert

I had my tree's insert function create a new Node that contains a deep copy of the data parameter.

Block 1:

```
insert(Object* toInsert){
    ...
    Node temp;
    temp->data = new Object(*toInsert); //deep copy toInsert
    ...
}
```

I figured this was the more solid implementation because it avoids privacy leaks. However, this resulted in a memory leak because another component (given by the prof.), does not delete the Objects it passes to insert(). My destructor would deallocate Nodes correctly, but not the original data passed to insert().

I fixed the memory leak by changing my code to Block 2.

Block 2:

```
insert(Object* toInsert){
    ...
    Node temp;
    temp->data = toInsert; //directly toInsert to data
    ...
}
```

I thought of a third solution, but decided my insert function should not manage another component's memory.

Block 3:

```
insert(Object* toInsert){
    ...
    Node temp;
    temp->data = new Object(*toInsert); //deep copy toInsert
    delete toInsert; //manages another component's memory
    ...
}
```

My gut tells me Block 3 is a no-go. Am I correct?

When dealing with data structures is it better to insert data directly like in Block 2 or to make a deep copy like in Block 1?

Thanks

Comment: The third option is pointless. If you own the parameter to the point you can `delete` it during `insert`, you own it to the point you can *retain* it until your tree node meets it's demise and avoid the needless alloc+copy. I would go with Plan B and confirm that decision by clarifying with your prof if their *intent* was to pass ownership (and thus cleanup responsibility) to your tree

Comment: If you look at the [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) they use standard copying for all their members. That means if you have a container of pointers the pointers are copied, and if you have a container of objects the objects copy- or move-constructors are called, or the copy- or move-assignment operators are called. Then it's up to each class to implement the copy-/move-semantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the signature of your interface functions so that that their treatment of the arguments with respect to ownership transfer is unequivocal.

For option 1, where the function copies the input argument, pass the object by (const) reference rather than through a pointer:

```
insert(const Object& toInsert){
    ...
    Node temp;
    temp->data = new Object(toInsert); //deep copy toInsert
    ...
}
```

For option 2, where the function assumes ownership of the argument object, pass the object through a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
insert(std::unique_ptr<Object> toInsert){
    ...
    Node temp;
    temp->data = toInsert.release();
    ...
}
```

Option 3 doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot use std::unique_ptr because the school's Linux lab uses a '98 compiler, so I have to use a plain pointer.

Comment: @shtuken With an old compiler you can use `std::auto_ptr` (which is the predecessor of `std::unique_ptr`).